# Replacement for context.showDocument() in JavaWebStart application

Tags: java, browser, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm migrating an old legacy application from in browser applet to a JFrame based JWS application started via JNLP.
In the applet base application I used the `context.showDocument()` to open Browser windows of any size and configured to not show bars (menu bar, status-bar, scroll bar) and not resizable (viawith Javascript ()).

But now this is not working.
Is there a workaround for that that I can do in a JavaWebStart/JNLP application?
I would need to open a HTML page and display the contend in a sized window without the usual bars.
When I use the `showDocument()` form JNLP basicServices now I can not do this (no JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should normally be possible to preview the html file inside a javafx webview, as it is with a normal java application. I am not sure about the jnlp  permissions required for this operation though:

```
private void previewHtml(String url) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            fr.add(fxPanel);
            fr.setSize(1000, 600);
            fr.setVisible(true);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Group  rootGroup  =  new  Group();
                    final Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup, 1000, 600, Color.WHITE);        
                    final WebView webView = WebViewBuilder.create().prefHeight(600).prefWidth(1000).build();
                    webView.getEngine().load(url);
                    rootGroup.getChildren().add(webView);
                    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                    fxPanel.show();
                }
            });                
        }
    });

}


//You can add the following code to a button actionListener:

//prevew html from classpath:
previewHtml(getClass().getResource("/classpath-file.html").toExternalForm());

//prevew html from url:
previewHtml("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: I'm ussing swing (JFrame, etc) is it a good Idea to mix it with javafx webview?

Comment: A second question: Why do we have here i the example twice the invoke/run later: java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater &  Platform.runLater; What is the reason for that?